# NER interfere with REGEXNER

Tags: scala, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I use regexner to find named entities that are not in the default set of Stanford NLP and it works fine. However, when I add ner annotator, it annotates tokens that match my regular expression with default tags. How can I overwrite default annotations?

```
def createNLPPipelineRegex(): StanfordCoreNLP = {
     val props = new Properties()
     props.put("regexner.mapping", "regex.txt")
     props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, regexner, pos, lemma, ner")
     props.put("tokenize.options", "untokenizable=noneKeep,normalizeParentheses=false")
     new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add regexner after the ner annotator it should work:

```
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner")
```