# Having both NER and RegexNER tags in StanfordCoreNLPServer output?

Tags: stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server

I am using the StanfordCoreNLPServer to extract some informations from text (such as surfaces, street names)

The street is given by a specifically trained NER model, and the surface by a simple regex via the RegexNER.

Each of them work fine separately but when used together, only the NER result is present in the output, under the `ner` tag. Why isn't there a `regexner`tag? Is there a way to also have the RegexNER result?

For information:

- StanfordCoreNLP v3.6.0
- the URL used:

  ```
  'http://127.0.0.1:9000/'
  '?properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner,regexner", '
  '"pos.model":"edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger",'
  '"tokenize.language":"fr",'
  '"ner.model":"ner-model.ser.gz", ' # custom NER model with STREET labels
  '"regexner.mapping":"rules.tsv", ' # SURFACE label
  '"outputFormat": "json"}'
  ```

  as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642008/ner-interfere-with-regexner), the `regexner` annotator is **after** the `ner`, but still...
- The current output (extract):

  ```
  {u'index': 4, u'word': u'dans', u'lemma': u'dans', u'pos': u'P', u'characterOffsetEnd': 12, u'characterOffsetBegin': 8, u'originalText': u'dans', u'ner': u'O'}
  {u'index': 5, u'word': u'la', u'lemma': u'la', u'pos': u'DET', u'characterOffsetEnd': 15, u'characterOffsetBegin': 13, u'originalText': u'la', u'ner': u'O'}
  {u'index': 6, u'word': u'rue', u'lemma': u'rue', u'pos': u'NC', u'characterOffsetEnd': 19, u'characterOffsetBegin': 16, u'originalText': u'rue', u'ner': u'STREET'}
  {u'index': 7, u'word': u'du', u'lemma': u'du', u'pos': u'P', u'characterOffsetEnd': 22, u'characterOffsetBegin': 20, u'originalText': u'du', u'ner': u'STREET'}
  [...]
  {u'index': 43, u'word': u'165', u'lemma': u'165', u'normalizedNER': u'165.0', u'pos': u'DET', u'characterOffsetEnd': 196, u'characterOffsetBegin': 193, u'originalText': u'165', u'ner': u'NUMBER'}
  {u'index': 44, u'word': u'm', u'lemma': u'm', u'pos': u'NC', u'characterOffsetEnd': 198, u'characterOffsetBegin': 197, u'originalText': u'm', u'ner': u'O'}
  {u'index': 45, u'word': u'2', u'lemma': u'2', u'normalizedNER': u'2.0', u'pos': u'ADJ', u'characterOffsetEnd': 199, u'characterOffsetBegin': 198, u'originalText': u'2', u'ner': u'NUMBER'}
  ```
- Expected output : I would like the last 3 items to be labelled with `SURFACE`, ie the `RegexNER` result.

Let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, things seem to work as I want if I put the `regexner` first:

```
"annotators":"regexner,tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner",
```

seems there is an ordering problem at some stage of the process?

Comment: Are you sure that the line above runs without errors?

Comment: Yes, it does with the setup described in the question.

Comment: If I run the code with the annotators order you mention in the answer it gives "annotator "regexner" requires annotator "tokenize""

Comment: Humm, this is strange. I don't know enough of Java to explain this. 
May it be related to locals LC_* (I run on a French system)?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what the [RegexNER documentation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html) says about this:

> RegexNER will not overwrite an existing entity assignment, unless you give it permission in a third tab-separated column, which contains a comma-separated list of entity types that can be overwritten. Only the non-entity O label can always be overwritten, but you can specify extra entity tags which can always be overwritten as well.
>
> > Bachelor of (Arts|Laws|Science|Engineering|Divinity) DEGREE
> >
> > Lalor    LOCATION    PERSON
> >
> > Labor    ORGANIZATION

I'm not sure what your mapping file exactly looks like, but if it just maps entities to labels, then the original NER will label your entities as NUMBER, and RegexNER won't be able to overwrite them. If you explicitly declare that some NUMBER entities should be overwritten as SURFACE in your mapping file, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

## Update for coreNLP 3.9.2 server via python:

When using coreNLP 3.9.2 server via python, the regexner can also now be initiated as part of ner [as per the docs](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html). For example:

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')

properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,coref,openie",
            "outputFormat": "json",
            "ner.fine.regexner.mapping":"rules.txt",}

output = nlp.annotate(text,properties=properties)
```

I could not get regexner annotator to work by calling it directly. I think this is due to reloading of dependencies and or the method used to translate outputs to JSON [e.g. this issue](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/472#issuecomment-312458926)